# PHP for and loop array

Tags: php, algorithm, structure

I just want to get a list of words from an array which has more and less than 3 vowels, but separately how can I do that with only for loop?

```
$name   = array('jake', 'rita', 'ali', 'addert', 'siryteee', 'skeueei', 'wsewwauie', 'aaaaweefio');

    $vowels = array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');

    $massiv = [ ];

    $vowel  = [ ];

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++) {

        $massiv[ ] = $name[$i];

        for ($j = 0; $j < count($vowels); $j++) {

            $vowel[ ] = $vowels[$j];
        }
    }
```

Comment: why only for and not foreach?

Comment: @clearshot66 - probably homework.....

Comment: `Has more and less then 3 vowels` - what does that mean exactly.  Does that mean 1 array with more and 1 with less (and if so what if there is exactly 3).  In my answer I mention this `This keeps the matches correlated to the original array`.. I'll leave that for you to think about.

Comment: No,l was told to get the list of names separately according to the count of vowels if there are more than 3 these names should be separated than those which has less than 3vowels but only with loop

Comment: 3 vowels in a row or 3 vowels total? Your wuestion is Unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Use Preg Grep:

```
$name = array('jake', 'rita', 'ali', 'addert', 'siryteee', 'skeueei', 'wsewwauie', 'aaaaweefio');
$vowels = array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');

$pattern = '/('.implode('|',$vowels).'){3}/i';

print_r(preg_grep($pattern, $name));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [4] => siryteee
    [5] => skeueei
    [6] => wsewwauie
    [7] => aaaaweefio
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/84e44dc1c450a4b92177b7a389dc1e9edca8ab0a)

The regex is pretty strait forward

```
/(a|e|i|o|u){3}/i
```

Match anything with at least 3 of any combination of the following `a|e|i|o|u`.  The `(..)` is a capture group, the `|` is or, the `{3}` is match 3 times. You could use `{3,}` 3 or more, but it doesn't really matter in this case because as soon as you have 3 you can quite looking.  The `\i` flag makes it case insensitive.

As long as each array item is a single word this should work fine, if you have multiple words it will be much more difficult to come up with a match.

**For Loop only**

Here I will do you the favor

```
$name = array('jake', 'rita', 'ali', 'addert', 'siryteee', 'skeueei', 'wsewwauie', 'aaaaweefio');
$vowels = array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');

$matches = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++) {
    $total = 0;
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($vowels); $j++) {
        $total += substr_count($name[$i], $vowels[$j]);
        if($total > 2){
            $matches[] = $name[$i];
            break; //exit inner loop
        }
    }
 }

 print_r($matches);
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d54e1091fe3c3ac9dd0b9908565738e0e852e6da)

The main thing here is

> int **substr_count** ( string **$haystack**, string **$needle** [, int **$offset** = 0 [, int **$length** ]] )
>
> **substr_count()** returns the number of times the needle substring occurs in the haystack string. Please note that needle is case sensitive.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

Same output as the first one.  However the nice thing about Preg Grep (besides case insensitivity) is it keeps the array keys, you can replicate this in the for each loop by adding the `$i` index in when adding matches:

```
$matches[$i] = $name[$i];
```

This keeps the matches correlated to the original array, something that may be useful in some cases.

If you want case insensitivity, the easy thing is to just lowercase the words.  There are some edge cases where this won't work but for most English words it should be fine.

```
  $name=strtolower($names[$i]); 
  //change $name to $names as it makes more sense
  //when adding to the match array use $names[$i]
  //that way we add the unmodified version to our matches
```

Also I should mention from a performance standpoint it's generally better to count outside of the for loop (condition).

```
$name_len = count($name);
for ($i = 0; $i <  $name_len; $i++)
//another way to do it is like this
for($i=0,$n=count($name);$i<$n;$i++)
```

**Summery**

So putting all that togather

```
$names = array('jake', 'rita', 'ali', 'addert', 'siryteee', 'skeueei', 'wsewwauie', 'aaaaweefio');
$vowels = array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');

$matches = [];
for ($i=0,$n=count($names);$i<$n;$i++) {
    $total=0;
    $name=strtolower($names[$i]);
    for ($j=0,$v=count($vowels);$j<$v;$j++) {
        //count lowercased version
        $total += substr_count($name, $vowels[$j]); 
        if($total > 2){
            $matches[$i] = $names[$i]; //use original in match
            break; //exit inner loop
        }
    }
}
print_r($matches);
```

You get about 12 lines of code that does the equivalent of one `preg_grep` call.

**LAST THING**

The code you had was just transferring the words and vowels to another array. Except you would wind up with `words*vowels` more vowels.  Because for each loop of the outer for loop (tied to words) you would do a full loop of all the vowels.

Anyway Enjoy!

Comment: But the other part l want both parts of the words